# C++98 template class static member initialization?

Tags: c++, c++98, gcc4.4

In a large C++ code base, originally written @ 2001, a Singleton class
is used heavily, and is defined like:

```
   template <class T> 
   struct Singleton 
   { T *Instance() { return _instance; }
   ... 
     static T *_instance;
   }; 
   #define INIT_SINGLETON(T) \
    T * Singleton <T>::_instance = ((T*)0UL)
```

Now, with GCC 4.7.7, which I MUST use, with the default c++98 standard,
and a use of INIT_SINGLETON(structX) in a test file, I get:

```
   $ g++ -std=c++98 -c /tmp/ts.cpp 
   /tmp/ts.cpp:11: error: too few template-parameter-lists
```

The code last compiled OK with GCC 3.4.3 on Linux RHEL3 - I am trying to port
it to RHEL6 (GCC 4.4.4 / 4.7.7).

It's been a while since I used C++98 code, though I've used C++ since @ 1994 ,
I can't seem to get my head around this one today.

Could anyone please shed some light on why this error occurs and how to avoid it ?

In response to S.M.'s & NathanOliver's request, this is
/tmp/ts.cpp:

```
    template <class T> 
    struct Singleton 
    { T * Instance() { return _instance; } 
      T * _instance; 
    }; 

    struct ab_s { int a, b; }; 

    typedef Singleton<ab_s> S_ab_s_t; 

    ab_s* f(S_ab_s_t sa)
    { return sa.Instance(); 
    }

    ab_s * Singleton<ab_s> :: _instance = NULL;
```

GCC 4.7.7 gives error:

```
    $ g++ -std=c++98 -Isonim/MRFP/inc -c /tmp/ts.cpp  
    /tmp/ts.cpp:15: error: too few template-parameter-lists
```

Comment: `Singleton <T>` -> `Singleton<T>`?

Comment: could be a parsing issue.  Does the error go away if you remove the white space between the name and parameter and have `T * Singleton<T>::_instance = 0`?

Comment: Please post the [mcve]. You already have it: tmp/ts.cpp:11, the file seems to be small.

Comment: no - I am paraphrasing the actual code, which has no space there.

Comment: We can't help you debug code that isn't what you are showing us.  Please edit this to have a [mre].

Comment: The code you’ve now posted is *completely different* from the original code: `Singleton` isn’t a template, its `_instance` member isn’t `static`, and there’s no macro.

Comment: Note on formatting: you must put  ```  in a separate line, otherwise it will consume anything in the same line looking for formatting specification.

Comment: Why mess with a macro if you want the same initialization for all specializations? Just define `template<class T> T* Singleton<T>::_instance = NULL;` right under the class template and GCC will sort it out.

Comment: @StoryTeller:
I don't think I can do that and remain C++98 / C++03 compatible.
Will try.

Answer (score 1):

Template specialization requires template<>.

```
#define INIT_SINGLETON(T) \
    template<> \
    T * Singleton<T>::_instance = ((T*)0UL)
```

The compiling example

```
template <class T> 
struct Singleton 
{
  T *Instance() { return _instance; }
  static T *_instance;
}; 

#define INIT_SINGLETON(T) \
  template<> \
  T * Singleton<T>::_instance = ((T*)0UL)

struct structX{};

INIT_SINGLETON(structX);
```

To the updated question:

```
template<>
ab_s * Singleton<ab_s> :: _instance = NULL;
```

Comment: AHH! Thank you so much! It's been a while since I used this feature.
I remember now.

Comment: gcc could definitely give a more informative diagnostic there.

Comment: @JVD It does! — Nowadays (“specializing member 'Singleton<ab_s>::_instance' requires 'template<>' syntax”).